# In terminal how do i quickly move to directory

Tags: file, terminal, find, directory

How do I most efficiently move to directory if there are many embedded folders?
Currently I, cd into folder, ls, the cd into folder 2 and so forth until I find the folder I need.  Is there a faster way to complete this task.  A way to find the files in a specific main directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you know where you're going you can create an `alias` that'll take you to the requested directory, for example, in bash:

```
alias dir="cd /path/to/your/directory"
```

Add this alias to your dot-files and it'll be loaded whenever you open a shell, then all you'll have to do is type "dir" and hit Enter.

Another option that can help you locate the directory in case you don't know what it is - but you know a specific filename of a file that lives under that directory is to use:

```
find . -name filename
```

to find the file (with its full path).

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://pypi.org/project/fastcd. It stores recently visited directories and allow to cd to the desired one.